# c# change array name in a for loop

Tags: c#, arrays, for-loop

Is it possible to change the arrayname in a for loop?
My Arrays are called T1, T2 T3...
now I want to replace the number behind the T into an int.
Here my code:

```
sql = con.CreateCommand();
sql.CommandText = "select [ZeitH] from [Tisch 1] where [Datum]='" + datum + "';";
OleDbDataReader reader = sql.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read())
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        if (reader.GetInt32(0).ToString() == (i + 10).ToString())
        {
            T1[i] = false;
            T1[i + 1] = false;
            T1[i + 2] = false;
            T1[i + 3] = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure that you can change a collection's name while you are iterating

Comment: You want the T1 change to T2 and etc. ???

Comment: I've reformatted your code to include the body of the `if` statement as normal vertical statements. Even if you'd normally put several statements on a line in your code (which I wouldn't recommend) it makes things particularly hard to read on Stack Overflow where there is limited horizontal space.

Comment: You can solve this problem using reflection but it's unlikely that it is the best possible solution. Just use jagged array instead `T[][]` and use `for` loop to iterate through your arrays.

Comment: why not create a function that takes a reference to T, and runs the for loop on the reference ? then it would be a matter of calling the function T1, T2, ..., TN times

Comment: now I want to replace the number behind the T into an int, when and till which no, if you know this then add your arrays into a list of Arrays and use a linq to get the desired array? @Suren Srapyan has explained this using Temp and if "your condition" block.

Answer (score 4):

If I understood you right - You can create an reference(name **Temp**),and assign to it T1.Then in the `for` loop you can iterate on that **Temp** reference, and if you want to change your array you can assign **T2** to your **Temp**.

```
sql = con.CreateCommand();
sql.CommandText = "select [ZeitH] from [Tisch 1] where [Datum]='" + datum + "';";
OleDbDataReader reader = sql.ExecuteReader();

var Temp = T1;

while (reader.Read())
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        if (reader.GetInt32(0).ToString() == (i + 10).ToString())
        {
            if( your condition)
            {
                Temp = T2;
            }

            Temp[i] = false;
            Temp[i + 1] = false;
            Temp[i + 2] = false;
            Temp[i + 3] = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If i understood you right, you want to replace the "1" after the T to some other number depending on some condition.

I would recommend you to store your arrays in a list or in another array (any ordered collection will do) and not keeping x Tx variables.

Something like:

```
List<bool[]> list = new List() { T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6 }; // add all your arrays, best generate the arrays in a loop and add them to the list in that loop

for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
{
    if (reader.GetInt32(0).ToString() == (i + 10).ToString())
    {
        if(someCondition)
        {
            x = 1; // eg. take the T2 array if condition matches
        }
        else
        {
            x = 2; // eg. take the T3 array if condition does not match
        }
        list[x][i] = false;
        list[x][i + 1] = false;
        list[x][i + 2] = false;
        list[x][i + 3] = false;
    }
}
```